# How to access the property of an object?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have implemented a function `u()` that can transfer the result from servers to the outside so that I can do something out of the `success:function()`. However, I don't know how to get the result "y" from _pass. I have tried _pass.y but got an error message. 
Also, "y" was successfully assigned.

```
var _pass = {};
_pass = function(y) {
    alert(y);
    return y;
};

function u(pass) {
    $.ajax({
        /* ... */

        success: function(html,pass) {
            pass(html);
        }
});}
```

Comment: Btw.: the choosen names of methods and params are not good to keep the code clear!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var _pass = {};
_pass = function(y) {
    console.log(y);
    return y;
};

function u(pass) {
    var methodName = pass;

    $.post(location.href, function(data) {
        methodName(data);
    });

}
u(_pass);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nZnFM/8/

Comment: Maybe you don't need the variable methodName, maybe you can use the pass parameter directly in ajax callback method.

Comment: isn't defined in _pass = function(y) {
    console.log(y);
    return y;
}; ?

Comment: No no, you can't use _pass as function() and as object {}. First you have defined the object, then the method, but the method overwrites the object totally afaik. To keep the object you should create a new function inside of the _pass object. For example: _pass.doThis = function(){}. Then you can use it as object and fill any properties you want.